# Using open_mfdataset to stack xdatasets

Tags: python-xarray

I have a set of xdatasets I want to stack ontop of each other effectively making each grid point an array. I only want this for a single variable, `ws10m_mean`, since I will be grabbing a grid point using lat/lon. I have tried to use `open_mfdataset` to achieve this goal but get the error:

```
xr.open_mfdataset(f"{args.i}wind_summary_hprcc_*.nc",concat_dim=[None,None,...],data_vars='ws10m_mean',combine='nested')
ValueError: concat_dims has length 3 but the datasets passed are nested in a 1-dimensional structure
```

The stacking xdatasets look like:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     (gust_cat: 3, rose_group: 80, latitude: 726, longitude: 10020)
Coordinates:
  * gust_cat    (gust_cat) int64 1 2 3
  * rose_group  (rose_group) int64 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80
Dimensions without coordinates: latitude, longitude
Data variables:
    lat         (latitude, longitude) float64 34.14 34.14 34.14 ... 50.54 50.53
    lon         (latitude, longitude) float64 -111.8 -111.8 ... -88.06 -88.03
    ws10m_mean  (latitude, longitude) float64 5.2 5.293 5.863 ... 11.47 11.47
```